# How to calculate the tatal using .reduce on dart map

Tags: dart

I have a map like this:

```
{id2: {quantity: 6, name: NEW NAME}, 1484: {quantity: 1, name: NEW NAME 404}, id: {quantity: 34, name: NEW NAME}}
```

here I have a key called **"quantity"** what i need to do is calculate the total quantity , for this example **6+1+34 = 41** , maybe using `.reduce` method but can't find how to implement it on a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it make more sense to use `fold` which you can read about here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Iterable/fold.html

```
void main() {
  final map = {
    'id2': {'quantity': 6, 'name': 'NEW NAME'},
    1484: {'quantity': 1, 'name': 'NEW NAME 404'},
    'id': {'quantity': 34, 'name': 'NEW NAME'}
  };

  final sum = map.values
      .fold(0, (int sum, element) => sum + (element['quantity'] as int));

  print(sum); // 41
}
```

But if you really want to use `reduce` you can do it like this:

```
void main() {
  final map = {
    'id2': {'quantity': 6, 'name': 'NEW NAME'},
    1484: {'quantity': 1, 'name': 'NEW NAME 404'},
    'id': {'quantity': 34, 'name': 'NEW NAME'}
  };

  final sum =
      map.values.map((e) => e['quantity'] as int).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  print(sum); // 41
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, You're a gem to the mankind.....

Comment: I think the fold method is bettter.